# Bootstrap crash after adding v-model to input fields

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue

I am new ai Vue.js. I made simple table with 4 input fields, and put that in form and when form submit I just want to output that data to console. I used bootstrap for table just to look better. I used class table table-bordered. And it looks good, but when I add v-model to input fields, so I can pick up users input, bootstrap crash, and table looks ugly. this is my code:

```
<template>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="home" style="width: 600px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Registracija korisnika</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align: left">Ime:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="inputName" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align: left">Prezime:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="inputSurname" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align: left">Mejl:</th>
          <td>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" v-model="inputMail" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align: left">Lozinka:</th>
          <td>
            <input
              type="password"
              class="form-control"
              v-model="inputPassword"
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HomeView',
  data() {
    return {
      inputName: '',
      inputSurname: '',
      inputMail: '',
      inputPassword: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      var user = {
        name: this.inputName,
        surname: this.inputSurname,
        email: this.inputMail,
        pass: this.inputPassword,
      };
      console.log(user);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Question is why my bootstrap crash? I can style it with css, but I think it is better to use bootstrap. Does anyone have idea why this happen? Bootstrap version is 5.1.3 and boostrap-vue is 2.21.2 [image: This is whithout v-model attribute to input fields] [image: this is how it looks when I add v-model to input fields]

Comment: What does your `console` say?

Comment: nothing, console is empty